# How to force solr QParserPlugin not to use whitespace tokenizer for Keyword fields?

Tags: solr, query-analyzer, solr-query-syntax

I have keyword field in Solr schema.

```
<fieldType name="text_keyword" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.SimpleKeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When I try to search this field with default solr query or dismax query
`category:(Mouse Pad)` it creates query `(category:Mouse) AND (category:Pad)`

I want to know is there a way not to split terms by whitespaces if it is keyword field or so.

Added:
I need `SimpleKeywordTokenizerFactory` analyze (which is lowercase without white-space splitting) on query, so `raw` and `term` query parser doesn't work for me

Comment: Looks like there is an open issue about it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1122

Answer (score 1):

You want to enter this query:

```
category:"Mouse Pad"
```

The query syntax already provides a way to do this. Quotes are for phrases. Parentheses mean something different. You can write your own query parser if you want, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TermQParserPlugin](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/search/TermQParserPlugin.html):

{!term f=category}Mouse Pad

Beware that no analysis is performed, so this will only work if the internal representation of your field is "Mouse Pad" (with title case).

**Edit** (2012-04-17):

If you still want analysis to be performed, all you need to do is to escape the space by prepending a backslash:

{!lucene}category:Mouse\ Pad

Comment: Yes I can also do this with {!raw} . But actually I want to do some field analyze(like lowercase). The only think I don't want is white-space splitting and keyword analyzer don't do this, but query parser does...